# List of laser-cooled atoms and ions

Tags: atomic-physics, laser

I'm familiar with the requirements for an atom or ion to be cool-able with laser cooling -- a closed transition -- or close enough that the leaks can be plugged with repumpers. But is there a list of all such atoms or ions for which this is either (a) possible or (b) experimentally realised?

Comment: Maybe you can check this database :
http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html

Comment: This doesn't specify which species might be laser cooled. Going through the level diagrams for each one is a serious task.

Comment: For atoms, at least, I have found this:
http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2013/08/19/know-your-laser-cooled-atoms/

I think it's only those that have been achieved, and isn't counting ions, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes I wanted to add "but you will have to go through the diagram level" but I was not allowed to edit my message any more. Btw the link you provided is really nice